# An isolated point of $A$ is not a limit point of $A$. Why?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, definition

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

> If $X$ is a metric space, a point of $x_0$ of $X$ is said to be a **limit point** of the subset $A$ of $X$ if every $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x_0$ intersects $A$
> in at least one point different from $x_0$.

> Note that given $x_0\in X$ it may happen that for some $\delta>0$, the $\delta$-neighborhood of $x_0$ consists of the point $x_0$ alone. In that case, $x_0$ is called an **isolated point** of $X$, and $\cdots$

If $x_0$ is a limit point of $A$, then there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n\in A$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0$.
So, a limit point of $A$ is a limit of a sequence in $A$.
This is ok.

Let $x_0$ be an isolated point of $A$.
Let $\{y_n\}$ be a sequence such that $y_n = x_0$.
Then, $\{y_n\}$ is a sequence such that $y_n\in A$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=x_0$.
$x_0$ is a limit of a sequence in $A$, but $x_0$ is not a limit point of $A$.
Why?

I wish if an isolated point of $A$ were a limit point of $A$.

Comment: You haven't given your definition of "isolated" point yet. And "limit point" says, we nee at least one point different from $x_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of limit point misses the important restraint that $x_n\neq x_0$, else any point of $A$ would be a limit point. And since if $x_0$ is an isolated point then if $x_n\to x_0$ in $A$ we must have $x_n=x_0$ for also $n\geq N$ for some $N$ we get this property.

Comment: Lazy, Thank you very much for your answer.